# Ruby - Find the longest non-repeating substring in any given string

Tags: ruby

I am working on an assignment where I have to take user input of a string and search through it to find the longest non-repeating string in it. So for example:

If the string is:

```
"abcabcabcdef"
```

My output needs to be:

"`abcdef` is the longest substring at the value of 6 characters"

---

**Here is my poorly made code:**

```
class Homework_4

  puts "Enter any string of alphabetical characters: "
  user_input = gets
  longest_str = 0
  empty_string = ""
  map = {}
  i = 0
  j = 0

  def long_substr()
    while j < str_len
      if map.key?(user_input[j])
        i = [map[user_input[j]], i].max
      end
      longest_str = [longest_str, j - i + 1].max
      map[user_input[j]] = j + 1
      j += 1
    end
    longest_str
  end

  long_substr(user_input)
end
```

---

I have been working on this for over 6 hours today and I just can't figure it out. It seems like the internet has many ways to do it. Almost all of them confuse me greatly and don't really explain what they're doing. I don't understand the syntax they use or any of the variables or conditions.

All I understand is that I need to create two indicators that go through the inputted string searching for a non-repeating substring (sliding window method). I don't understand how to create them, what to make them do or even how to make them find and build the longest substring. It is very confusing to try and read the code that is full of random letters, symbols, and conditions. I'm sure my code is all sorts of messed up but any help or tips that could point me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: 'non-repeating' is unclear - does it mean no double appearance of any letters? or not containing any other substring in the string outside of the chosen substring?

Comment: The longest non-repeating substring obviously is the string itself. It's clearly the longest substring and cannot be repeating. What's that? I misunderstood what you meant by "non-repeating"? Well then you need to edit your question to define what you mean by "non-repeating".

Comment: @Cary Swoveland I find question is pretty clear. Once you encountered the same character you have to stop and calculate the length ,Likewise we have to do until we find the longest string. And his example output makes it more clear.

Comment: @Rajagopalan, I have a rough idea what is wanted but would still like to see an unambiguous statement of the question. For one, it is good practice for developing code specifications, which similarly need to be complete and precise.

Comment: @CarySwoveland The questions makes itself very clear without having any unambiguous statement.

Comment: Mr. Jett, for your example why isn't the longest substring, "bcabcdef"?

Comment: It is not clean what you mean by "longest non-repeating substring". Can you provide a *precise* specification of what it is that you want to happen, including any and all rules, exceptions from those rules, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases? Can you provide sample inputs and outputs demonstrating what you expect to happen, both in normal cases, and in all the exceptions, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases? For example, why is the longest non-repeating substring not simply the string itself? It is by definition the longest substring and it …

Comment: … cannot possibly be repeating either; therefore the longest non-repeating substring is trivially always just the input string.

Comment: Mr. Jett, when posting a question to SO you have a responsibility to address questions for clarification in a timely matter. You have not done so, wasting reader's time and displaying a lack of appreciation for the assistance generously provided by the SO community. You may be new to SO but it should be obvious that you should not post a question and then just walk away. You need to edit your question to precisely define what you mean by "non-repeating" strings, and include a few examples of both "repeating" and "non-repeating" strings.

Answer (score 1):

```
def uniq?(s)
  # All letters of s uniq?
  return s.chars.uniq == s.chars
end

def subs(s)
  # Return all substrings in s.
  (0..s.length).inject([]){|ai,i|
    (i..s.length - i).inject(ai){|aj,j|
      aj << s[i,j]
    }
  }.uniq
end

def longest_usub(s)
  # Return first longest substring of s.
  substrings(s).inject{|res, s| (uniq?(s) and s.length > res.length) ? s : res}
end
```

`ruby`'s `inject` is actually a `reduce` function, where `inject(optional_start_value){<lambda expression>}` - and the `lambda expression` is similar to Python's `lambda x, y: <return expression using x and y>` just that lambda expressions are strangely written in Ruby as `{|x, y| <return expression using x and y>}`.

Python's `range(i, y)` is Ruby's `i..y`.

Python's slicing `s[i:j]` is in Ruby `s[i..j]` or `s[i,j]`.

`<<` means add to end of the array.

#### Second solution (inspired by @Rajagopalan's answer)

```
def usub(s)
  # Return first chunk of uniq substring in s
  arr = []
  s.chars do |char|
    break if arr.include? char
    arr << char
  end
  arr.join
end

def usubs(s)
  # Return each position's usub() in s
  (0..s.length).to_a.map{|i| usub(s[i,s.length])}
end
      
def longest_usub(s)
  # return the longest one of the usubs() over s
  usubs(s).max_by(&:length)
end
```

then you can do:

```
longest_usub("abcabcabcdef")
## "abcdef"
```

Answer (score 1):

I have asssumed that a string is defined to be *repeating* if it contains a substring `s` of one or one more characters that is followed by the same substring `s`, and that a string is *non-repeating* if it is not repeating.

A string is seen to be repeating if and only if it matches the regular expression

```
R = /([a-z]+)\1/
```

[Demo](https://rubular.com/r/HucPjJ4ETajMrQ)

The regular expression reads, "match one or more letters that are saved to capture group one, then match the content of capture group 1".

For convenience we can construct a simple helper method.

```
def nonrepeating?(str)
  !str.match? R
end
```

I will perform a binary search to find the longest non-repeating string. First, I need a second helper method:

```
def find_nonrepeating(str, len)
  0.upto(str.size-len) do |i|
    s = str[i,len]
    return s if nonrepeating?(s)
  end
  nil
end
```

```
find_nonrepeating("abababc", 7) #=> nil
find_nonrepeating("abababc", 6) #=> nil
find_nonrepeating("abababc", 5) #=> nil
find_nonrepeating("abababc", 4) #=> "babc"
find_nonrepeating("abababc", 3) #=> "aba"
find_nonrepeating("abababc", 2) #=> "ab"
find_nonrepeating("abababc", 1) #=> "a"
```

We may now implement the binary search.

```
def longest(str)
  longest = ''
  low = 0
  high = str.size - 1
  while low < high
    mid = (low + high)/2
    s = find_nonrepeating(str, mid)
    if s
      longest = s
      low = mid + 1
    else
      high = mid - 1
    end
  end
  longest
end
```

```
longest("dabcabcdef")
  #=> "bcabcdef"
```

Comment: This answer is wrong. Question says same char should not be repeated.

Comment: @Rajagopalan: Where does it say that? Neither the word "same" nor the word "char" appears anywhere in the question. The word "character" appears twice but not in any context that seems to support your claim. All I can find in the question is the term "longest non-repeating substring" with no definition of what "non-repeating" means. My interpretation of the specification is the longest substring which is not repeated within the original string, which is actually just the original string itself. Cary's interpretation is different than mine, but that does not make it wrong; it makes the …

Comment: specification imprecise. This answer is not wrong. Either the answer is correct or the question is off-topic for being unclear.

Comment: @JörgWMittag No matter whatever he explains, his input and output made it very clear as to what he wants.

Comment: @CarySwoveland this regex is wrong, because it says "take any sequence of alphabetic characters of the minimum length of 1 and capture it" and the `\1` says the captured sequence should appear again. - it doesn't mean that the occurrence should be maximum 1x within the string ... so ... it is wrong.

Comment: @Gwang-JinKim, please provide an example of a repeating string `s` (consistent with my definition of a repeating string) for which `s.match? R #=> false` or a non-repeating string `s` for which `s.match? R #=> true`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland it is not trivial in regex I fear. It must be with negative lookups. But the problem is the negative lookup must be searching for letters occurred until a position. Look at my answer - it will be more understandable without regex than with regex. - in my answer the function `usub()` checks for the longest stretch without repeating character starting at position 0. You will see, translating that into a regex is not trivial at all.

Comment: @Gwang, you said my regex is wrong. To support that assertion you need to provide a counter-example, as I requested in my previous comment. Please note that we have different understandings as to what constitutes a "non-repeating string".

Comment: @CarySwoveland Take the string "abcdc" - the first repeating character is the second `c`, thus, "abcd" is the unique substring starting from position 0. Your regex would slurp the entire thing into this `([a-z]+)`. And since `\1` is not there your regex doesn't match this string at all - for that two substrings must repeat immediately one after another according to your regex. This is not the case in this string.

Comment: By my assumption of what constitutes a "repeating string" neither 'c' is a repeating substring as it is not immediately followed by itself. Again, our assumptions about what constitutes a repeating substring differ. Please evaluate my regex against my definition. While it is true that the regex engine would initially match "abcdc" when it failed to then match \1 it would backtrack, eventually concluding that there is no match.

Answer (score -1):

```
a = "abcabcabcdef"
arr = []
words = []
b=a
a.length.times do
  b.chars.each do |char|
    break if arr.include? char
    arr << char
  end
  words << arr.join
  arr.clear
  b=b.chars.drop(1).join
end

p words.map(&:chars).max_by(&:length).join
```

Output

```
"abcdef"
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for me. Exactly what I needed. Idk why you got downvoted, thank you! I would upvote this if I had enough karma to do so.

Comment: @Mr. Jett hi, Accept the answer If I have answered your question. There is a hallow tic on the left top corner of the answer you have to click there so that it becomes green.